# How to convert native sql to grails/gorm

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Can I convert this to GRAILS/GORM. If yes, any help please.

```
select b.id, b.username, b.first_name, b.last_name
from tb_user_orgpermissions a
inner join tb_user b on a.username = b.username
where
(a.department_id = :dept_id)
and (a.agency_id = :agy_id)
```

Comment: Could you be more precise. Do you want to create GORM domains for above query or you want to convert it to gql or criteriaQuery or hql.

Comment: I want to convert it to grails createCriteria.

Comment: Please specify your domain class and explain your query.

Answer (score 0):

To create the equivalent query as a gorm criteria query, the first thing you need is domain classes (with proper associations) for each table. As an example, here's some pseudo code:

```
class User {
    String username
    String firstName
    String lastName

    static hasOne = [permission: UserPermission]
}

class UserPermission {
    Department department
    Agency agency
}

class Department {}
class Agency {}
```

In this example `User` has a [one-to-one](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-associations/#onetoone) association to  `UserPermission`.

With something like this in place you can create a criteria query (with [projections](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-select-clause/)):

```
User.withCriteria {
    projections {
        property 'id'
        property 'username'
        property 'firstName'
        property 'lastName'
    }

    permission {
        department {
            eq 'id', dept_id
        }

        agency {
            eq 'id', agy_id
        }
    }
}
```